# Uniform convergence on singleton

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

First, recall the definition of uniform convergence:

Consider functions $f_{n}:A\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. The sequence of functions $f_{n}$ converges uniformly on set A to limit function f if $\lim\underset{x\in A}{\sup}|f_{n}\left(x\right)-f\left(x\right)|=0$

I see no restrictions on what A can be. But if I let A be singleton, then there will be no difference between pointwise and uniform convergences, so $f:\{1\}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $f\left(x\right)=x^{n}$ converges uniformly on set $\{1\}$.

Second, recall the theorem that states: $f_{n}$ converges uniformly on $S_{1}$ and converges uniformly on $S_{2}$, then $f_{n}$ converges uniformly on $S_{1}\cup S_{2}$.

Now, let $S_{1}=[0,1),S_{2}=\{1\},f_{n}=x^{n}$. Hence, $x^{n}$ converges uniformly on $[0,1]$, which is wrong because it's well-known that uniform convergence holds only on $[0,1)$ for that function.

What went wrong?

Comment: Since when does $x^n$ converges uniformly on $[0,1)$ ? Here's the fallacy in your "proof".

Comment: I think you've mixed up uniform convergence and one of its most common applications.  It's true that $f_n=x^n$ converges to a continuous function on $[0,1)$, and it's true that the limit of sequence of continuous functions that converges uniformly is continuous, but it's not true that just because the limit is continuous that the sequence of functions converges uniformly.  $x^n$ does not converge uniformly on $[0,1)$.

Comment: ok, forget about that function. What about uniform convergence at singleton?

Comment: @nikolai What are you asking exactly now ?

Comment: The theorem on unions will only extend to finite unions.  It is true that convergence and uniform convergence is the same on a singleton set, or any finite set.

Comment: @Callus, thank you very much! That's kind of answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question "what went wrong":

The series of functions $f_n$, defined by $f_n(x)=x^n$, does not converge uniformly on $[0,1)$.

Comment: oh, sorry. But it wasn't the point of my question. It was just an example. If there is no difference between pointwise and uniform convergence on signleton, then I could use theorem about uniform convergence on union of sets and claim that any pointwise convergent sequence becomes uniform one.

Comment: @nikolai Which theorem about uniform convergence on a union of sets? Can you cite exactly what the theorem states?